# Is there a way with Jackson ObjectMapper (without a custom @JsonCreator) to unmarshall this Json to the supplied Java Dto?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have two Java classes:

```
public class Request
{
    private List<Item> subItems;

    public Request()
    {
    }

    public List<Item> getSubItems()
    {
        return subItems;
    }

    public void setSubItems(List<Item> subItems)
    {
        this.subItems = subItems;
    }
}

class Item
{
    private String name;
    private String functionName;

    //...elided...
}
```

The `subItems` that will be passed can be complex (include a function) or simple (just a name). There can be a mix of these. To simplify the JSON, I'd like to be able to accept the following:

JSON:

```
{
  "subItems": [
    {
      "name": "complexType",
      "function": "someFunction"
    },
    "simpleType"
  ]
}
```

and then have this turned into the *equivalent* of the following instance:

```
Request request = new Request();
request.setSubItems(
    Arrays.asList(
        new Item( "complexType", "SomeFunction" ),
        new Item( "simpleType" )
    )
);
```

Is this possible with Jackson/ObjectMapper?
What settings and annotations would I need?

Comment: You should try your custom way to put json to corresponding map i.e. play with JSONObject, and then get all the values corresponding to entries, and then add all the values to your Item list.

Comment: @Jabongg I would prefer not having to do a custom json creator or to just marshall it to a map, because then i can't use validation annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Item` class has a string constructor, it will be called with the `"simpleType"` value.

```java
class Item {
    private String name;
    private String functionName;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getters and setters here
}
```

*Full demo*

```java
public class Request {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\"subItems\":[" +
                          "{\"name\":\"complexType\",\"functionName\":\"SomeFunction\"}," +
                          "\"simpleType\"" +
                      "]}";
        Request request = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Request.class);
        System.out.println(request);
    }

    private List<Item> subItems;
    public Request() {
    }
    public Request(Item... subItems) {
        this.subItems = Arrays.asList(subItems);
    }
    public List<Item> getSubItems() {
        return this.subItems;
    }
    public void setSubItems(List<Item> subItems) {
        this.subItems = subItems;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Request [subItems=" + this.subItems + "]";
    }
}
```

```java
class Item {
    private String name;
    private String functionName;
    public Item() {
    }
    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Item(String name, String functionName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.functionName = functionName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getFunctionName() {
        return this.functionName;
    }
    public void setFunctionName(String functionName) {
        this.functionName = functionName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [name=" + this.name + ", functionName=" + this.functionName + "]";
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Request [subItems=[Item [name=complexType, functionName=SomeFunction], Item [name=simpleType, functionName=null]]]
```